# Compression String does not work for all strings

Tags: javascript

The idea is to complete the function and produce a compressed form of the string given. An example would be if the given string was `aabbcc` then you would get `a2b2c2`

The issue with the code I created is for some reason it does not work with anything right away that is consecutive or consecutive letters at the end. `wwww` turns into `w4` but `aa` does not turn into `a2` and `wuenuneubgnjfniwfibwiebfaaa` will not turn into `wuenuneubgnjfniwfibwiebfa3`

```
function compressedString(message) {
  let out = '';
  let count = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    let current = message[i];
    let next = message[i + 1];
    if (current == next) {
      count++;
    } else {
      out += current + String(count);
      count = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work-ish, it's appending `1` though, so not sure how you're getting the intended output. https://jsfiddle.net/b15o0gpm/

Comment: It is working for 'wuenuneubgnjfniwfibwiebfaaa'. it gives 'w1u1e1n1u1n1e1u1b1g1n1j1f1n1i1w1f1i1b1w1i1e1b1f1a3'.

Comment: Surprised it worked at all, wouldn't next = message[i+1]  goes out of the string when it reaches the last character of the message?

Comment: @Dhara , I would like that if the character only shows up once then to omit the 1 and only place a number if it is 2 or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test your algorithm, using given example of your question `wuenuneubgnjfniwfibwiebfaaa`, the output was `w1u1e1n1u1n1e1u1b1g1n1j1f1n1i1w1f1i1b1w1i1e1b1f1a3`, what sounds strange for the string compression requirement. When I add a nested condition inner first `else` in `for` loop, I acquired the correct result, please view the code bellow and let what do you think about:

```
 function compressedString(message) {
  let out = '';
  let count = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    let current = message[i];
    let next = message[i + 1];
    if (current == next) {
      count++;
    } else {
      if(count == 1){
        out += current;
      }else{
        out += current + String(count);
      }
      count = 1;
    }
  }
 return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the way you are handling it in the end. What happens to the variable `next` when the loop is on the last iteration? You need to add an extra check on your `if`.

Try this:

```js
function compressedString(message) {
  let out = '';
  let count = 1;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
    let current = message[i];
    let next = message[i + 1];
    if ( i < message.length-1 && message[i] == next) {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      out += current + String(count);
      count = 1; 
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```